# AD Domain question

Tags: active-directory, login-name

In active directory on the user properties dialog and the account Tab there is a field.  The first textbox at top left is "User login name:”, to the right of that there is a dropdown with @domain.local.  Does anyone know what property or object needs to be populates to put a value here when creating user programmatically?

Comment: this should probably be on serverfault

Comment: no, it should definitely be on serverfault :)

Answer (score 0):

That's the `userPrincipalName` (UPN). You typically set it to the value of `sAMAccountName` and add @domain.local. If your using the `dsadd user` command you need to specify the -upn parameter for this to be populated.

Comment: NewUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value =strLoginName; Populates the only "User login name:” field 

NewUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = "@MyDomain.local"; Popluate only the domain field 

NewUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = strLoginName + "@MyDomain.local"; Populates both..... Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: Always use NewUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = strLoginName + "@MyDomain.local"; - setting just one will result in errors. userPrincipalName is stored as a whole string in AD. If you're happy with the answer click on the up arrow and the check mark to accept my answer.